# Convert number to character in hebrew date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I build label with the date for today (hebrew date)

its work but is number and not character

for exapmle:28/4 to 28 Tavat

code:

```
NSLocale *hebrew = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"he_IL"]; // Hebrew, Israel
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSHebrewCalendar];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat.locale = hebrew;
dateFormat.calendar = calendar;
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
[_label setText:dateString];

NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

NSLog(@"hebrew: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
[formatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the style to medium or higher:

```
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

If you use the medium style then the month will be abbreviated, switch to the long style (`NSDateFormatterLongStyle`) for the full month name.